House built with people in the walls
This is a horror movie with 10-20 years, english, about a couple that goes to a house. I dont think they moved there, but I dont remember why. Strange things start happening (walls bleeding, hands come out of the walls) and eventually it is found that the house was built with people in its walls, because some legend believes it makes the house stronger.
There's a part of the movie showing this religious belief and how the architect did this for several houses. I also remember someone else is living there. The person is crazy and eventually tries to kill the protagonists, I think. I also seem to remember some sort of well in the attic (?) where the protagonists end up being stuck.

I immediately found the answer on Google just after posting it here. It is Walled In:

A young woman who recently graduated from engineering school travels
  to a remote location to supervise the demolition of a mysterious
  building. She soon discovers the horrifying secrets of the building
  and its past inhabitants, many of whom were victims of a vicious
  murderer who entombed his prey alive within its walls. Now she must
  turn the tables on the killer before she becomes his latest victim.

